# Drupal: Comments to users from admin/manager

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I am looking for a way in drupal for users to get comments from the administrator/manager. I would like a block that each of the users sees with personal comments from the manager to that user. Only managers can make comments and only the user the comment is intended for can read the comment. Is there a module or an easy way to do this? Any ideas would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Do the comments have to be comments as defined in Drupal, where they're attached to nodes? And are you using Drupal 6?

Answer (score 2):

You can break the problem down into two parts:

1. Create a content type that has create/edit permission restricted to an admin/manager role and has view permissions restricted on a per-user/per-node basis.
2. Create a block that filters nodes of this type to only show ones that the user can view.

---

This is my hypothetical approach:

1. Create a new content type for your user comments.

   - Use either nodeaccess or content_access to provide access control to this type. Both have views integration and are actively being ported to D7. I'd recommend content_access as it's integrated into ACL, a decent module that provides a reusable access control API.
   - Using content_access, "Enable per node access control settings" under the content type's "Access control" tab. This gives admins the option to set who can view each comment.
2. Create a view with a block display. Filter for the content type. Comments that a user isn't allowed to view should automagically be excluded.